# How to create new tag?

Tags: feature-request, tag

There's some missing tags must be added to be used by the community.
I couldn't find a way to add new tag, is it privileges problem or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags can be created by any user with 150 reputation.  Rather than selecting an existing tag from the pulldown list, simply type out the new tag name manually (no more than 25 characters, no spaces) when writing a new question, or editing an existing one, and it will be created.

Further details can be found on the relevant help page: [Help Center > Privileges > Create Tags](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)